# Bootstrap 5 Accordion: make arrows rotate 90 degree instead of 180 degree

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap-5, bootstrap-accordion

I created a **Bootstrap 5** Accordion like here https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/accordion/. By default, the arrows are rotated 180 degree, when the item is open (from 'v' to '^'). But I want the arrow to rotate just 90 degree (from '**>**' to '**v**').

I tried to manipulate it by exchanging variable values:

In _variables.scss I set `$accordion-icon-transform: rotate(90deg);` (instead of bootstrap 5 default `$accordion-icon-transform: rotate(-180deg) !default;`)
and I exchanged the arrow svg from a 'v' (bootstrap 5 default) to a '>'

The outcome is, that on first page load, the arrows look like 'v' (I want a '>').  When I open the accordion item, it shows a 'v' (correct). Then I close it and the arrow looks like desired '>'. But **I want the arrow to show '>' with the first page load**.

Is there a way to achieve this, only by manipulating the bootstrap variables? Or do I have to write some extra JS on top of collapse.js?

Comment: I think you can use this code in css or scss.
`.accordion-button::after {rotate(-90deg) !important}`

Comment: This didn't work, unfortunately. Now the arrow always shows upwards '^' and doesn't rotate at all anymore.

Comment: Then, add `.accordion-button::after {transform: rotate(-90deg) !important}` and  `.accordion-button:not(.collapsed)::after {transform: rotate(-180deg) !important;}`.

Answer (score 0):

Now, I found a solution with pure CSS:
In my custom style.scss, I added:

```
.accordion-button&[aria-expanded="false"]::after {
  transform: none;
}
```